# add non-indexable document to alfresco using java

Tags: java, lucene, alfresco

I succeded to add content to alfresco using java with

```
FileInfo fI=serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService().create(fileInfo.getNodeRef(), "test.docx", ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT);
serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService().getWriter(fI.getNodeRef()).putContent(new File("C:\\......\\test.docx"));
```

but my purpose is to add a content that is not indexable so it doesn't appear in any lucene results , is that possible ?

Comment: I think that https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/admin-indexes.html is what you are looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify, you only want the document you've added not to be indexed as opposed to not indexing everything of that type?

Comment: yes I just want the paper I added is not indexed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's simple i have to add a property to the node

```
nodeService.setProperty(res.getNodeRef(),
                ContentModel.PROP_IS_INDEXED, "false");
```